# I am displaying contents of a java array in reverse order of input, but only half the array is being displayed

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I'm doing a foundations course on Java, and the task is to create a program where a user inputs 10 strings into an array, the have the program display them back to the user in the reverse order of which they were input.

Here is the relevant code so far

```
String []stringarray = new String[10];

public void add()
{
    System.out.println ("Enter 10 Strings :");
    for ( int i=0; i<10  ; i++ )
        stringarray[i] = Genio.getString(); 
}

public void display()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10/2; i++)
    {
        String tmp = stringarray[i];
        stringarray[i] = stringarray[10 - i - 1];
        stringarray[10 - i - 1] = tmp;
        System.out.println (stringarray[i]);
    }
}
```

So when I input, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0, I should receive 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 back.

However I only receive 0 9 8 7 6.  I think it might be to do with the "i<10/2;" in the for line, but i'm not sure.

Comment: You should print them after ordering (in another loop) or just simply loop the array backwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to display the array backwards, there's no need to swap elements around - just loop from 9 (10-1) down to 0 and print the elements:

```
public void display()
{
    for (int i = stringarray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println (stringarray[i]);
    }
}
```